# how to set up and deactivate a single key event in vba routine?

Tags: vba

I'm new to vba and want to automate some processes. I wanted to ask, if there is an opportunity to set up a macro where within the main subroutine I am asked to select a certain cell and hit a predefined key sequence. As a result I'll get cell coordinates and the macro terminates and the key sequ. does no longer trigger any macro behavior.

Comment: Not clear what you asked. At least, for me... So, do you want running a subroutine **which asking the user to select a certain cell** and do something only if you enter a "predefined key sequence", as it can be understood from the  question? Or you need to press a key(s) combination (like a shortcut) and make the macro running? What " key sequ. does no longer trigger any macro behavior" should mean? This sentence made me thinking of a shortcut keys combination...

Comment: thx :-)
your're right, I should give more context! 
So there are 3 excel files at play here:
-> one sheet with my main data
-> one sheet containing the macro
-> one sheet where my macro will be triggered which depends on specific user case, call it use-file

Comment: I want to write data from the data file into the use-file. Before inserting, data will be filtered and altered depending on the specific use case.
My data is sored in a relational style and the destination area within the use-file is of relational style as well.
The critical part is that the desination area is not fixed and will depend on individual case where my question comes in.
The workflow would look somehow like this:

Comment: I start my macro, clicking on an appropriate button in the excel ribbon within the use-file.
Depending on the specific use-file, data from my data workbook will be loaded and filtered within an ado recordset. 
A messagebox will now ask the user the select, say upper left corner of the area where the data will be inserted and hit for example "control + i". 
Pressing "control + i" will now trigger an inserting subroutine. After that the combination "control + i" is no longer bind to any sub.
Data is inserted and the macro will terminate.

does that help?

Comment: A too long answer against my clarification request... So, you cannot call another macro during the time another one runs. But you can do it if the message is the last line of the running code. And take care to remove the shortcut when that specific sub ends. I will post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

1. Run the `testMacro1` Sub. It will set `Ctrl + Alt + i` shortcut for the macro `testCalledMacro`. `Ctrl + i` and `Alt + i` already exist and not recommended to redefine them...;
2. Being on an Excel worksheet press `Ctrl + Alt + i`. The invoked macro should work. But, at the end, it will deactivate its own shortcut.

```
Sub testMacro1()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print i
  Next i
  Application.OnKey "^%{i}", "testCalledMacro"
  MsgBox "Please, select a cell in column A:A and press ""Ctrl + Alt + i""."
End Sub

Sub testCalledMacro()
  Dim i As Long
  MsgBox "I am running..."
  Application.OnKey "^%{i}", ""
End Sub
```

3. Press again `Ctrl + Alt + i`. Now, it will  not work, anymore...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Sven_Mo: Didn't you find some time to test the above recommendation? If yes, didn't  it work as you need?

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot! Did manage to test only yesterday, but it worked very well. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Sven_Mo:  Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody supply an answer to our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the solution works...